# 18.04 super key window placement

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I have upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04, and the super key + arrows works inconsistently.

Nautilus File windows, Settings and some Libre Office programs no longer respond to any of these placement commands.  Dragging the windows will not give the left or right half-screen placement either, and only whole-screen highlighting occurs.

Most of my installed apps do respond as expected (including Nemo Files)  but in the case of Libre Office:
Writer, Calc and Base do not, but Impress, Draw and Math do.  If I open two of the latter the first three will behave as expected while those are open but not when they are closed again!  The Help pages respond correctly whichever program they are opened from.

Comment: This happened to me, too. It seems weird that some of apps one needs most (Writer, Calc) cannot snap left or right after I updated to 18.04.

Comment: I reported this bug also to LibreOffice and MM commented: Could you try another desktop (x11) and see if it solves the problem ? Wayland may be enabled as default, but sometimes not working correctly with every program.

Comment: Following up that suggestion:  1.   only Desktop options available  Wayland (default), Ubuntu and LXPt.  LXPt  goes nowhere (have to shut down with the computer's power button).
2.  On Ubuntu, Writer, Calc and Base will respond correctly to the superkey + arrow commands if any other LibreOffice program is running, but not if they are open alone.  Otherwise, things are exactly as described for Wayland.
3.  But Wayland is now responding in exactly the same way!